# Animation not firing un jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, python-multithreading

Using below code within a cell in Jupyter notebbok I'm attempting to update a simple graph :

```
%reset -f 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

# animation function. This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    line.set_data([1,random.randint(100,101)], [1,random.randint(100,101)])
    return (line,)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20)

rc('animation', html='jshtml')

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

But this is the output that is rendered :

[image]

How to dynamically update the graph with data ?

Using `line.set_data([1,random.randint(100,101)], [1,random.randint(100,101)])` is the not the correct method to add data ?

For now I'm just attempting to update within the result of a call to `random` but I plan to use this with the result of a REST service.

Comment: What is `get_x_y` supposed to return?

Comment: @rpanai I've update the question and removed that function, it was a function I tried to implement in order to update the graph.

Comment: are you trying to do a sort of dashboard? In that case why don't you have a look at plotly dash or [panel](https://medium.com/@philipp.jfr/panel-announcement-2107c2b15f52)?